# Question about a notation.

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

I have a question about the notation in [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3929). On page 8, the 3-rd line from bottom, it is said that $h_J(t)$ is the corresponding diagonal matrix in $GL_4$. I think that $J$ is some set such that where $\alpha_J=\sum_{j \in J} \alpha_j$ is a root. For example, let $h_J(t)$ in $GL_6$ and $J=\{3,4,5\}$. What is $h_J(t)$? Why $\alpha_J(h_J(t))=t^2$? Thank you very much.

Comment: The two number version of $J$ is $(3,6)$ and $h_J(t) = h_{3,6}(t)$ is the diagonal matrix whose 3rd entry is $t^{-1}$ and whose 6th entry is $t$ and whose other diagonal entries are 1, so that $\alpha_J(h_{3,6}(t)) = t / t^{-1} = t^2$. In general $\alpha_{ij}(d) = d_j / d_i$ where $d$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: The paper might have the inverses switched. It mostly doesn't matter, but it might mean some of my $t^{-1}$ are their $t$ and vice versa.

Comment: @JackSchmidt, thank you very much.